# Two thread diffrent run method and work concurrently

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I want to run two thread with different run method concurrently. Is it possible? I have simple code below but they don't work concurrently. I simply want to run first thread every 5 sec and second thread always.

```
public static int x = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

    Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            x = x + 1;
            System.out.println("increment x");
        }
    };

    Runnable r2 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("x is "+x);
        }
    };

    while(true){
        Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t1.sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: a) You shouldn´t start running already threads in an endless loop. b) You aren´t synchronizing the access to x. c) Concurrent console output will result in problems.

Comment: 3) Thread.sleep() is static and lets the *current* thread, not the referenced thread sleep (as with static methods, there's no such thing)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public class Test {
public static int x = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

    Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while(true){
            x = x + 1;
            System.out.println("increment x");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
        }
    };

    Runnable r2 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while(true){
            System.out.println("x is "+x);
            }
        }
    };
        Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
```

//          Thread.sleep(5000);

```
}
```

}

something like this.. but keep in mind points made above

Comment: Please give an explanation.

Comment: This is just to show how it is supposed to work. Accessing a static variable like that would probably result in errors. The same variable might be used at the same time by both threads leading to unpredictable result. To avoid that use synchronization as @JB explained below.

Answer (score 3):

Your `run()` methods only increment x, print it, and return. As soon as the run method returns, the thread stops running. If you want something to run forever, you need a loop inside the `run()` method.

Moreover, accessing a shared variable without any kind of synchronization won't lead to predictable results. Your `x` variable should at least be volatile. And finally, Thread.sleep() is a static method. It should thus be called using the class name:

```
Thread.sleep(5000L);
```

It makes the *current* thread sleep.

Here is an example where one thread increments x every 500 millis, one other thread prints x every 100 millis, and both threads are interrupted after 5 seconds:

```
public class ThreadExample {
    private static volatile int x;

    private static class Incrementer implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                x++;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500L);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static class Reader implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                System.out.println(x);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100L);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Incrementer());
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Reader());
        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000L);
        }
        finally {
            t1.interrupt();
            t2.interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But if i add while loop in the run methods, when first thread (t1) begin to run, the second (t2) will never begin to run.

Comment: Why do you think so? The whole point of threads is to be able to run concurrently. Your program currently starts dozens of threads, each doing one or two operations: increment x and print it.

Comment: Isn't that what you want? If not, please explain what you want. The first thread should increment the value evert 5 seconds and stop when? The second thread should print the value continuously and stop when? Should the thread stop running by themselves, or should the main thread ask them to stop, and if so, when?

Comment: See my edited answer for a thread-safe example running for 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

In the while loop, you are each time creating new `Threads` then `start` each of them that's why you having such behaviour.

Then you will need to move the while loop inside the threads so they lool like below:

```
public static volatile int x = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      while (true) {
        x = x + 1;
        System.out.println("increment x");
        this.sleep(5000);
      }
    }
};

Runnable r2 = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      while(true){
        System.out.println("x is "+x);
      }
    }
};
 Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
 Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);
 t1.start();
 t2.start();
}
```

Note also that your `x` variable should be accessed synchronously to see the correct value.

BR.

Comment: This code still has problem. At least variable x need to be either volatile or eventually AtomicInteger for thread synchronization.

Comment: The goal of the synchronization is not to avoid deadlock. The goal is to be able to see the correct value. Code without synchronization will never deadlock. But it will display incorrect results.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Thread t1;;
    Thread t2; 
while(true){
      t1 = new Thread(r1);
      t2= new Thread(r2);
      t1.start();
      t1.sleep(5000);
      t2.start();

}
```

you are adding code is right putting code up t1.sleep(5000)  before t2.start().